# Typeorm don´t save migrations in the correct folder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When starting a project with Nest.js using TypeORM, I using the archive ormconfig.json with the commands below.

But when using in terminal the command **npm run migrate:create -n test** the project saved the migration archive in the root folder, and don't saved following the configuration folder in ormconfig.json

Where is the error? How to make the migration archive going to typeorm/migration folder?

```
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "root",
    "database": "ferrari",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": false,
    "entities": [
        "typeorm/entity/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "migrations": [
        "typeorm/migration/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "subscribers": [
        "typeorm/subscriber/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "cli": {
        "entitiesDir":"typeorm/entity",
        "migrationsDir": "typeorm/migration",
        "subscribersDir":"typeorm/subscriber"
    }
}
```

This is the structure directory

```
-src
-typeorm
   -migrations
ormconfig.json
package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching about this problem, i found the solution making the fix below:

I changed `omrconfig.json` per `omrconfig.ts` folow this model

```
export default {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'test',
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  "entities": [
      "src/typeorm/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
       "typeorm/migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/typeorm",
      "migrationsDir": "typeorm/migrations",
      "subscribersDir": "src/typeorm"
  }
};
```

Then I installed the typeorm CLI global with

`npm i -g typeorm`

And add two scripts in `package.json`, the first is:

`"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config server/environments/migrations.ts"`

And the second is:

`"migrate:create": "typeorm migration:create \"./typeorm/migrations/"`

So I managed to save the migrations in the chosen folder inside typeorm/migrations with the terminal command

`npm run migrate:create -n {migrationName}`

This typeORM version is 0.3.6

Comment: could you please also include Typeorm version you are using

Comment: @MathGainz I'm using this version: 0.3.6